# plot density function

Tags: r

A random variable Y has a distribution with density f given by

```
f(y)= y-1/6 if 1<=y<=4

  -(y-5/6) if 4<=y<=5

   0  else
```

Use R to produce a plot of the densityfunction of Y .
 This is my question how do i plot it using R program?

Comment: whats with the python? shouldn't you retag?

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse`

```
  (y <- c(1:6)) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
(fy <-  ifelse(1<=y & y<4,  y-1/6, ifelse(4<=y & y<=5, -(y-5/6), 0)))
[1]  0.8333333  1.8333333  2.8333333 -3.1666667 -4.1666667  0.0000000
plot(fy~y, type='l')
```

[image]

I assumed the following:
if 1 <= y < 4  then    y-1/6
4 <= y <=5     then  -(y-5/6)
y>5            then      0

This avoids the overlaping you have in 1<=y<=4 and 4<=y<=5